# Why Does Checking compute concatenation var (suffix_ALL) in JSON path extractor Not Always Work?

Tags: jmeter

I have two POST calls. I have a JSON extractor in each, with the exact same configuration.

I've noticed that when I run it, the response data in my debug sampler is not always the same. Meaning, that I've checked "compute concatenation var(suffix_ALL)," but I only sometimes get it for each. I get a combination or only one of myvar, myvar_ALL, or myvar_n.

For example, in the debug sampler I may see for POST 1:

```
myLinkList={"linkList":[{"label":"item1","link":"link1"},{"label":"item2","link":"link2"}]}
```

For example, in the debug sampler I may see for POST 2:

```
myLinkList={"linkList":[{"label":"item1","link":"link1"},{"label":"item2","link":"link2"}]} 

myLinkList_1={"label":"item1","link":"link1"}
myLinkList2={"label":"item2","link":"link2"}

myLinkList_ALL={"linkList":[{"label":"item1","link":"link1"},{"label":"item2","link":"link2"}]}
```

Why is this? How can I make sure the myvar_ALL variable comes up in the debug sampler, so my beanshell post processors can use it instead of getting EOF errors because the variable value doesn't exist? I could use "myLinkList" instead of "myLinkList_ALL," but there's no guarantee that it will pop up either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 possible reasons for this:

1. The response data is different in 2 cases, when you have only one match therefore concatenation var is not being generated
2. The problem is caused by using Beanshell PostProcessors. When it comes to high loads or large data sets Beanshell can become a performance bottleneck and may ruin your test so consider switching to [JSR223 Post Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language as:

   - [Groovy supports modern Java features and provides a plenty of enhancements on top](http://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html)
   - [Groovy has built-in JSON support so you will be able to get rid of these JSON Extractors and parse responses by Groovy means](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
   - [Groovy performance is much better comparing to Beanshell and other scripting options](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).